# Drawbacks or side-effects when compiling PHP with --enable-maintainer-zts (to use php pthread)

Tags: php, php-pthread

I have a web application and is running fine with PHP 5.5.5 on a production environment.

On the same server now I need to run some PHP scripts that make use of php pthread (v. 2.0.10)

**Is it safe** to rebuild php with `--enable-maintainer-zts` (to allow use of pthreads) and use the same executable **both** for the web application and the CLI scripts that use php-pthread **?**

Or should I make two builds of PHP: `php`, `php-zts` and use the former for the web app and the latter for the CLI scripts ?

As `--enable-maintainer-zts` is not enabled by default I assume it have some drawbacks or worse (as I have read here https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/985) may introduce misbehaviours (bugs).

The web stack is **nginx** + **php-fpm** + **mySql** on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

I want it to be clear: **phtread** will **not** be used by the web application scripts. Only by the CLI scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_php.html

*(emphasis mine)*

> `--enable-debug` enables debug mode
>
> [...]
>
> `--enable-maintainer-zts` enables thread-safety.
>
> [...]
>
> **you should not use either of these options** if you want to perform performance benchmarks for your code, **as both can cause significant and asymmetrical slowdowns**.

`--enable-maintainer-zts` seem not harmful but affects performances. So it's definitely not advisable in a production environment.

A separate build of PHP with `--enable-maintainer-zts` in order to use php pthread in CLI scripts is the appropriate way to go.